# “undefined singleton method” error for Module, though method is listed within singleton_methods

Tags: ruby, singleton

I’m a bit disappointed by `singleton_method`/`singleton_methods` behaviour. Say, we have the following module:

```
module M
  extend self
  def m_i 
    puts "m_i"
  end 
  def m
    puts "include? = [#{singleton_methods.include?(:m_i)}]"
    puts "call = [#{singleton_method(:m_i).call}]" rescue puts $!
  end 
end
```

The output of a call to `M::m` will be surprisingly:

```
# include? = [true]
# undefined singleton method `m_i' for `M'
```

The method seems to be listed within `singleton_methods` array (which is fine, due to `extend self` directive,) but is not callable, which is frustrating. By explicit defining the method as singleton (`self.m_i`) it became callable.

What am I missing?

---

**UPD** The method `singleton_method` was introduced in `2.1` and it looks like I have met a bug in implementation.

**UPD2** Filed as https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10092

Comment: Are you sure the error message is `undefined singleton method 'm_i' for 'M'`? because mine is `undefined method 'singleton_method' for M:Module` and I use ruby 2.0. The two are different.

Comment: I’m as sure as I trust copypaste feature. `ruby-2.1.2`. It nevertheless does not explain why `undefined`.

Comment: Can you give me the doc link of `singleton_method` ? I am not seeing here - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_method

Comment: @mudasobwa okay... I'm going to try 2.1. The error message of mine is caused by `M.methods.include? :singleton_method # => false` which   means `Module` doesn't have method `singleton_method`. But `Module` inherit from `Object`. That's strange.

Comment: @WindorC Looks like `singleton_method` was introduced in `2.1`, since it’s doc exists for `2.1` only.